# EF5 not Saving Modified Collection

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have `List<Employees> emplist = new List<Employees>` in that I am adding three times.

```
emplist.add(emplist1)
Then functionality here for emplist2
emplist.add(emplist2)
Then functionality here for emplist3
emplist.add(emplist3)

_context.AddRange(emplist)
_context.SaveChanges()
```

when I add in the Db it's adding only emplist1.In debugger in AddRange do see empllist have all 3 collection but in db it saves only emplist1.any body pl help in this.

Comment: Are we sure emplist1,2,3 variables are not holding one and the same object instance?

Comment: yes not same instance I am adding new emp inside the list.In add range i do see all combined list but in db it saves only first collection.I am using SqlliteDB.

Comment: What actually is the type of emplist1,2,3? I was assuming they are just poorly named variables, but you also wrote *all 3 **collection**"*. Hope they are not really lists, `AddRange` expects list of objects (entities), not list of lists.

Comment: Can you post the class of Emplist1 and where you create it?

Comment: yes able to find out seems like same list was referenced and overwritten Thanks Dan and Ivan

Answer (score 1):

actually same list was refrenced and fixed. Also in sqllite results are paged not like sqlserver where all shown in  one grid. so thought its not added after clicking the page resultset in sqllite able to see the results.